# Can we use Amazon-vpc-cni-k8s network plugin in cluster created with kubeadm tool?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-vpc, kubeadm, cni

I have a Kubernetes cluster created using kubeadm tool in AWS instance. I used the "Weave" Network plugin. I just saw amazon-vpc-cni-k8s plugin in EKS Documentation. So can I use this Network plugin in my cluster created by kubeadm tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to separately run the amazon-vpc-cni-k8s command.

`kubectl apply -f aws-k8s-cni.yaml` from [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s)

Alternatively you could use [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray) that allows you to configure the CNI plugin as part of the deployment

Comment: kubectl apply -f aws-k8s-cni.yaml this command I can give in k8s master node right?         so It is possible right?

Comment: If kubectl is installed on the master than yes